# Custom Shortcode w/ Custom $tax_query Attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, attr, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create a custom shortcode in Wordpress that will let me place an attribute to specify a category and query within a custom post type called "case_studies". The taxonomy itself is called "case_study_categories" and I've set the default to be "furniture-interior", as you can see.

What I need is for the shortcode to look something like this:
[get_project_gallery order="ASC" tax_query="flooring"]

Ideally, the shortcode attribute I've placed would override the default of "furniture-interior" and instead use "flooring" to display the appropriate posts. Actually, I would think I don't even really need a default defined at all (so it would just get all the case_studies posts if no attribute is specified) but I can't get that to work either.

BTW, the attribute for order works exactly the way I would want - it overrides the defined default. I just can't figure out how to get this done with the $tax_query.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance all!
Here's my code:

```
function project_gallery_function($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date',


            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'case_study_categories',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'furniture-interior'
                        
                )
             )


    ), $atts));

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'case_studies',
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'order' => $order,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'tax_query' => array($tax_query)





);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '<aside class="grid-gallery four-col grid-gap-4">';
  
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();

    $gallery_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    echo '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" class="x-image mobx sub-img" data-rel="gallery-1"><img src="'. $gallery_thumb .'" alt="" /></a>';

  }
  
  echo '</aside>';
  
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();


}
add_shortcode( 'get_project_gallery', 'project_gallery_function' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be worrying about the whole entire `tax_query` unless you plan on actually redoing the whole `tax_query`. You should consider changing it to just using `$terms` instead, since that's the only part you're replacing with the shortcode (you don't need to rebuild the whole array).

Secondly, make sure your code is normalized with your spacing and indentation - future you appreciates the forethought!

Lastly, you could consider passing even more variables to the array to make it a bit more extensible - `$posts_per_page`, `$taxonomy` etc.

```
function project_gallery_function( $atts, $content = null ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'terms' => 'furniture-interior',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'taxonomy' => 'case_study_categories',
        'post_type' => 'case_studies',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
    ), $atts ) );

    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => $field,
            'terms'    => explode(',', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $terms)), // Force to array, allowing comma sep values
        )
    );

    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => $post_type,
        'post_status'    => 'publish', 
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'order'          => $order,
        'orderby'        => $orderby,
        'tax_query'      => array( $tax_query )
    );
    
    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ){
        echo '<aside class="grid-gallery four-col grid-gap-4">';
            while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
                $the_query->the_post();

                if( $gallery_thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $page->ID, 'thumbnail' ) ){
                    printf( '<a href="%s" class="x-image mobx sub-img" data-rel="gallery-1"><img src="%s" alt="" /></a>', get_the_permalink(), $gallery_thumb );
                }
            }
        echo '</aside>';
    }
    
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'get_project_gallery', 'project_gallery_function' );
```

A few other notes, [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) returns a falsey value if it doesn't exist, so you should wrap that in an `if` statement incase the image can't be found for some reason (corrupted, removed, forgot to add, etc). Also you have a `$page->ID` variable in `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` - but don't seem to have a `global $page` in the function? Make sure that's the variable you want to use there.

Using code like what I've provided will let you do what you want, `[get_project_gallery order="ASC" terms="flooring"]`, or even add multiple `[get_project_gallery order="ASC" terms="flooring,something-else,a-third-thing"]` - just match up the shortcode attributes with the parameter you want to override: `[get_project_gallery order="ASC" terms="flooring,something-else,a-third-thing" posts_per_page="15"]`

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers here! This is working exactly as I expect. Also appreciate your other notes... I changed the $page->ID to null and made a few other mods to suit my needs but, this got me down the road where I needed to be.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was missing the array() around $tax_query in my args and didn't notice